# How to create django database model that "knows" what kind of category it is?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, I have the following models.py

```
class Product(RandomPrimaryIdModel):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  price = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  condition = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class Mattress(Product):
  length = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  size = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Pillow(Product):
  shape= models.CharField(max_length=50)
  comfort= models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

The idea is that there's a "product" model and several "product_type" models. I'm trying to create a database scheme that relates the two. The end goal is so that when I given access to a primary id for an object whose product_type is unknown, I can simply query/filter that object to find out what the product_type is of the object.

I know that sounds a bit confusing, but how would I go about implementing the correct way? The current scheme (the one above) is not the correct solution I believe.

Comment: Better not to use `null=True` for `CharField`, ref [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/): "Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField unless you have an excellent reason..."

Comment: What are you going to do once you've got the product type? Wouldn't it be better to implement that behaviour as methods of your product types? So for example, a 'description' method for Mattresses would use its length and size, and that for Pillows would use its shape and comfort. Then code wouldn't care what type of object it was, it would just get its description. Normally explicit testing for classes in an OO framework is a red flag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs on multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) you can reference the lowercase name of the model.  In your case to find out the "product type" you'd do something like:

```
product = Product.objects.get(id=12)
try:
    mattress = product.mattress
    is_mattress = True
except Mattress.DoesNotExist:
    is_mattress = False
```

You could abstract this out to a helper method that would do the tests for you and return the type as a string or enum of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to an object, can't you use something like:

```
p = Product.objects.get(id=1)

class_of_p = str(p.__class__)
```

and then parse the resulting string

```
"<class 'whatever.models.Pillow'>"
```

to find what you need?  Apologies if I'm missing something.